# How to import sqlite file into app's document directory in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, import, export

I want to export my whole database from my app via email and on other device when i download that database file, it can be open directly in app and replace my existing database file with that database file.

I have exported my database file(.sqlite) via mail and i want to import that file from mail into my app. I have also implement the functionality which the file from mail can directly open in my app. But i want to import that database file directly from mail. So how can i do that?

Or Can i replace that file with my app database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for below method,

```
- (BOOL)replaceItemAtURL:(NSURL *)originalItemURL withItemAtURL:(NSURL *)newItemURL backupItemName:(nullable NSString *)backupItemName options:(NSFileManagerItemReplacementOptions)options resultingItemURL:(NSURL * _Nullable * _Nullable)resultingURL error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

you can call this method with `NSFileManager`'s instance or object. You can pass source and destination path as `fileUrl ([NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path string"];)` and it will replace data at destination path!

Comment: But what i have to write in Url to specify path of my file which downloaded from mail?

Comment: If you are downloading file that means it will stored somewhere, so find it out! Or show your code that how you getting that file!

Comment: I have not implement anything for import that file into my app. That i also want to know that how can i get that file from mail into my app.

Comment: When i download file from mail, i have implemented that file can be open in my app. But that file is not installed in my app's document directory

Answer (score 0):

This link is helps to all your questions in SQLITE,

Like **Copy Sqlite File in to Docs directory**,

and also Select queries, Insert, Delete, Update varius types of recotds etc.. etc...

Checkout ***`+ (NSString*) copyDBFile`*** method in this link for ur requirement

[*SQLite Programing : Initial Steps* - By **iOSCodeGUIDE**](http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2014/01/sqlite-programing-initial-steps.html)

```
//Commen method for DAtaBase Copy
+ (NSString*) copyDBFile
{
    NSString *docsDirectoryPath;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *databasePath;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDirectoryPath = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SqliteTable.db"]];

    BOOL isSuccess = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ];

    if (!isSuccess)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *defaultDBPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"SqliteTable" ofType:@"db"];
        // NSLog(@"path :%@", defaultDBPath);
        isSuccess = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

        if (! isSuccess)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);

    return databasePath;

}
```

Comment: ....No. If i replace my database file from my bundle then it will only copy blank database. I want to import database file from mail which contain already some data.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't understand your problem completely but here is a code that can give any clue how to replace your existing file in documents directory:

```
    //Reference the path to the documents directory.
    NSString *documentDir =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    //Get the path of old file.
    NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.sqlite"];

   if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: filePath])
   {
      [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] //Delete old file
   }
   //Copy New File.sqlite from Resource Bundle.
   NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"sqlite"];
   [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Comment: I don't want to replace database file with file from bundle. It will only erase existing database and copy new database file into document directory. I want to import database file from my email into my app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use iOS share extensions to first import the database file from mail app. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/share-extension-in-ios-8) that you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqlite.sqlite"];

NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourSqlite.sqlite" ofType:nil];

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;

if  (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqlite.sqlite"] ]) {

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourSqlite.sqlite"] error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Default file successfully copied over.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error description-%@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"Error reason-%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
}

_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```